# DateTime precision difference .NET vs Java

Tags: c#, java, .net, datetime, date

Im porting some calculation routines from .Net to Java but there seem to be some precision problems in the Date classes. Maybe I have stared myself blind on this but I cant figure out why the results differ.

How should I handle the dates to get the same numbers (milliseconds) across the platforms?

.Net

```
[Test] public void foo() {
    DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(2011, 2, 26, 19, 25, 24);
    DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(2011, 2, 28, 18, 40, 25);
    double millis = (dt2 - dt1).TotalMilliseconds;
    Assert.AreEqual(170101000, millis);
}
```

Java

```
@Test public void foo() throws Exception {
    Date d1 = createDate(2011, 2, 26, 19, 25, 24);
    Date d2 = createDate(2011, 2, 28, 18, 40, 25);
    long millis = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
    Assert.assertEquals(166501000, millis, 0.01);
}

private static Date createDate(int year, int month, int day,
        int hour, int minute, int second) {
    Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance();
    instance.clear();
    instance.set(year, month, day, hour, minute, second);
    return instance.getTime();
}
```

Comment: You are saying the formats are different, or they return different values? if they return different values, could that be because they are running a few ms apart?

Comment: Also don't use java Date in java, use Joda Date :)

Comment: Is Noda Time completed for .NET?  I know someone was working on a .NET port of Joda time...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wonderful!

**Problem:**

[Java Calendar months start at 0](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH) and [.Net Datetime months start at 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d7b9xsh.aspx#Y152).

So you are comparing .Net february to Java march. And, as Arjan suggested, on march 27th is the change to daylight savings time in many timezones.

This is a very common problem when using Java Calendar. To avoid it, you should use the named constants for the months like this:

```
Date d1 = createDate(2011, Calendar.MARCH, 26, 19, 25, 24); // Calendar.MARCH == 2
```

Comment: That indeed seems to be the problem. Using 0 - 11 for the months could easily lead to mistakes, as is the case here. It also fooled me.

Answer (score 1):

The difference in milliseconds is 3,600,000, so exactly 1 hour. Could it be that one language is using a different timezone setting than the other, where there is a change from or to DST?

I have done some more testing. The PHP result matches the C# result (only I get seconds instead of milliseconds) and my Java result matches your Java result. The problem seems to be a bug in the timezone handling in Java. According to Java the second time is in DST, which is not correct in my timezone (Europe/Amsterdam).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the problem is in the DateTime structure and not in the Double structure?  From the [documentation on the .NET Double data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx):

> Floating-Point Values and Loss of
>   Precision
>
> Remember that a floating-point number can only approximate a decimal
>   number, and that the precision of a
>   floating-point number determines how
>   accurately that number approximates a
>   decimal number. By default, a Double
>   value contains 15 decimal digits of
>   precision, although a maximum of 17
>   digits is maintained internally. The
>   precision of a floating-point number
>   has several consequences:

Since you're not returning fractional miliseconds, you can use the [System.Int64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64%28VS.71%29.aspx) (long in c#) data type.  Your value is within the allowed range for that data type.  The [max value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64.maxvalue%28VS.71%29.aspx) for an Int64 (long) is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused. Are you saying that the second (Java) test passes? Because I actually get the same number as the first (C#) test: 170101000.

Here is my test (which passes). I threw in JodaTime objects as an alternative to Date and Calendar:

```
@Test public void foo() throws Exception {
    DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(2011, 2, 26, 19, 25, 24, 0);
    DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(2011, 2, 28, 18, 40, 25, 0);
    Duration d = new Duration(dt1, dt2);
    Assert.assertEquals(170101000, d.getMillis(), 0.01);
    Date d1 = createDate(2011, 2, 26, 19, 25, 24);
    Date d2 = createDate(2011, 2, 28, 18, 40, 25);
    long millis = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
    Assert.assertEquals(170101000, millis, 0.01);
}

private static Date createDate(int year, int month, int day,
        int hour, int minute, int second) {
    Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance();
    instance.clear();
    instance.set(year, month, day, hour, minute, second);
    return instance.getTime();
}
```

Comment: @Arjan: JodaTime's DateTimeZone.getDefault().toString() is "America/Los_Angeles" on my system.

Comment: That explains why you don't have the problem. DST does not start on 27 March in your time zone, so all calculations are done correctly. If you want to reproduce the problem, try substracting 14 from the specified days (so change 26 to 12 and 28 to 14).

Answer (score -1):

It comes from the way you are subtracting.  In java you subtract 2 longs that represent times.  If you do a convert from the long back to the date it may not be what you set it to originally as there is some loss to the decimal place.  In .net you are subtracting actual dates and then converting to miliseconds.  So this result will actually be more precise.  If you convert the times in .net to total miliseconds then subtract i would bet you would find much closer results.